# PHP Laravel eloquent with multiple databases, actually select something

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am using two database connections in my Laravel project.

I need to modify tables in both databases.

I have set up everything and now I am playing around and trying to get data from the first and the second database, but the docs hardly give information on how to do so, I only found this:

```
$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
```

Are there more resources somewhere? I was not able to find anything.

So far I understand that I **cant use eloquent anymore** if I use multiple databases? At least I cant use eloquent for the second database, which is not default.

For testing, I have created the same tables on both databases with different data. But I cant query the data, I always get this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$User
```

Here are my tests:

```
 $users1 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->select('SELECT * FROM users');
 info($users1);

 $users2 = DB::connection('mysql')->User::all();
 info($users2);
```

I also tried:

```
$users1 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->User::all();
```

Best would be documentation on how to correctly use `DB::connection` and actually select, edit, insert data, etc.

**EDIT**

- How do I actually f.e. select all users from both databases?
- For the second database, I will never need to create new columns or tables, I will only need to update data, probably eloquent is not needed there, which means I always need to execute raw SQL, correct? If I use eloquent I need to create the models as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$users1 = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users')->get()->toArray();
```

For the second query you can do the same. There is no reason to use eloquent model for that. But if you want to then:

Inside your User model you must define your connection

```
 protected $connection = 'mysql'; //which is the default as well
```

And also you must define the fields that you want to be retrieved like:

```
protected $fillable = ['email','username'];
```

Really important is to hide sensitive fields like password etc etc. There you can use another array:

```
protected $hidden = ['password'];
```

Then you can use the eloquent like:

```
$users = User::get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful. I just figured out aswell that I dont need to change anything for the default DB.

Comment: Glad i helped :)

Comment: My problem is, how do I know this syntax: `->table('users')->get()->toArray();`. The laravel docu is really great, but the part on multiple databases is poor, there is only this one line: `$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);`. But I can figure that out step by step.

Comment: So basically this one casts your output of the users table into an array so you can use it. You can store it into a variable and access it as an array. This is a collection you can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the `setConnection` method

```
$someModel = new SomeModel;
$someModel->setConnection('foo');
$something = $someModel->find(1);
return $something;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

first you need to set the `config`

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql_live.database', 'dbname');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql_live.host','localhost');
```

then

```
 $result=DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users')->get();
```